# Loading a second version of jQuery into a new namespace?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've seen all the threads about loading different jQuery versions with .noConflict(), but I have a slightly more unique use case.

I am trying to load content with an ajax request on a page that already has an old version of jQuery installed (included and loaded). I want to essentially allow my ajax query to return code with a newer version of jQuery on a different namespace, so it plays nice with the existing page it is loading into.

Is there a pretty way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around more, I have solved this problem, so I figured I'd post incase anyone else has this issue. Basically, the hacky way I solved this was moving the preloaded version of jQuery to a temp namespace, loading the new version, moving it to our namespace, and then moving the old version back to the default. This is now working fine.